# Can anyone provide s minimal example of Hebrew/English document using Luatex/babel? (MacOS/TeXShop)

Tags: fonts, luatex, babel, hebrew

I am working on a novel, and I’d like to include very short bits of Hebrew. I can’t tell if I am having trouble with LuaLaTeX, babel, fonts or some combination.

Here is a short document (which doesn’t work) - I think the issue may be that the David font cannot be found - but maybe that’s wrong.

Does any of this look wrong:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hebrew-fonts}
\usepackage[hebrew, english, bidi=default]{babel}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{david}
\begin{document}

This is some text in english \sethebrew חלך \unsethebrew this is some English text.

\end{document}
```

How do you find the font named in TeXShop on MacOS? TeXLive says hebrew-fonts and culmus are both installed.

Answer (score 1):

The default style for Hebrew is not compatible with LuaLaTeX.

Two options for short texts in Hebrew with LuaLaTeX. With explicit markup (also with XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\usepackage[english, bidi=default]{babel}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{NewComputerModern10}

\begin{document}

Some text in English \foreignlanguage{hebrew}{חלך}. And more.

\end{document}
```

With automatic switching based on the script (only LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english, bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{hebrew}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{NewComputerModern10}

\begin{document}

Some text in English חלך. And more.

\end{document}
```

See the [page on Hebrew](https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/locale-hebrew.html) in the `babel` site.

Comment: When I tried your example,  I got the following error - which I think is a font error.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-hebrew/rlbabel.def
File: rlbabel.def 2023/08/22 v2.4a Right-to-Left support from the babel system 
Hebrew language support from the babel system


To avoid this error message,
run TeX--XeT or e-TeX engine instead of regular TeX.

/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-hebrew/rlbabel.def:45: Rig
ht-to-Left Support Error: use TeX--XeT or e-TeX engine.
l.45      engine}
               %
?

Comment: How do I determine what fonts were installed by TeXLive on macOS?

Comment: @MichaelWagner Have you modified the examples in some way?

Comment: let me check. I think that is exactly from your example.

Comment: I have exactly what you typed.

Comment: But the mwe you have provided in your other post is clearly different.