# How I determine the font name to use in a command like \babelfont{} from the package that install the font?

Tags: fonts, luatex, texlive, babel

I am using TeXShop on a Mac, and when I look at the installed packages, I see a couple of installed packages that include hebrew font - "culmus" and "hebrew fonts".

When  l look at the package contents, I see things like: david.tfm, and a number of .afm files with apparently associated names like DavidCLM-Medium.afm, and DavidCLM-Medium.otf, etc.

That leads me to believe that I should be able to use \babelfont{rm}{david}, but when I do that, I get an obscure TeX error that I think means it cannot find the font.

How do I find the correct font name to use?

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-hebrew/rlbabel.def
File: rlbabel.def 2023/08/22 v2.4a Right-to-Left support from the babel system
Hebrew language support from the babel system

To avoid this error message,
run TeX--XeT or e-TeX engine instead of regular TeX.

/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-hebrew/rlbabel.def:45: Rig
ht-to-Left Support Error: use TeX--XeT or e-TeX engine.
l.45      engine}
%
?

Here is the sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hebrew, english, bidi=default]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{David CLM}
\begin{document}

This is some text in english \foreignlanguage{hebrew}{חלך } this is some English text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Could you post the code of a small document we can compile to produce the error you're seeing? Which compiler are you using? You've tagged this `luatex`, but the output you posted suggests that might not be accurate. Also, please post the complete error. The first error you show isn't an error at all, so it isn't clear what the next line refers to. `(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-hebrew/rlbabel.def File: rlbabel.def 2023/08/22 v2.4a Right-to-Left support from the babel system Hebrew language support from the babel system` is just information.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705243/can-anyone-provide-s-minimal-example-of-hebrew-english-document-using-luatex-bab . I’d say you are still loading the default style for Hebrew with luatex.

Comment: Try `{David CLM}` as font name, if you use only david it will probably find the unsuitable type1 font.

Comment: @cfr, I modified the question to include may sample document.

Comment: Your mwe is wrong. See the other post for the correct setup.

Comment: @Javier Bezos - thank very much.  I will look at the post. What is "mwe"?

Comment: @MichaelWagner Minimal Working Example i.e. the shortest code people can use to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @JavierBezos - awesome - when  removed the hebrew from the \usepackage command, everything worked. Thanks and double thanks!

Comment: @JavierBezos - just for my own education, was it the case that when I included hebrew in the call to \usepackage{}, LuaLatex tried to load the default Hebrew, which was incompatible - and the \babelfont{} never executed? So when I took the hebrew out of the \usepackage{}, then that call succeeded, so then the \bablefont{} could execute with a compatible font?

Comment: @MichaelWagner The error has no relation at all to the fonts. The file `rlbabel.def` provides support for bidi writing in `pdflatex`.