# Why does my code don't write in hebrew

Tags: hebrew

I am trying to write a code in Overleaf and for some reason it gives me an error, and does not give me a proper output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.5cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\newcommand{\innerproduct}[2]{\langle #1, #2 \rangle}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{hebrew}
שלום לכם ילדים וילדות
\selectlanguage{english}
I am Yuval Hamevulbal

\end{document}
```

The output is:

```
I am Yuval Hamevulbal
```

The wanted output is:

```
שלום לכם ילדים וילדות
I am Yuval Hamevulbal
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is a *minimal* example?

Comment: What do you mean by minimal example

Comment: You need to use a font which has these letters, e.g. https://www.overleaf.com/read/dvsvgtwzxztw#604d97

Comment: How do I do that? Last semester I've done the exact thing I am doing now, but not it's not compiling me the code

Comment: @ArielFishbein see https://www.overleaf.com/read/dvsvgtwzxztw#604d97

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I tried copying your code to my overleaf, but it won't compile it now, do you know why

Comment: overleaf has an outdated support for hebrew with pdflatex. I wouldn't try to use it there. Either get a local, current texlive 2023 on your PC, or use on overleaf lualatex (or xelatex) for hebrew.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ohh Ok I get it, I just thought that maybe there might be some ridiculous reason for the error, e.g \usepackage{amsmath} so I just left it all there

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/705244/2388 for a lualatex example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But I used Overleaf for hebrew last year, and it worked perfectly fine

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What is lualatex? Is it a different coding language?

Comment: well I just tried on overleaf and it used `hebrew.ldf 2003/11/01 v2.3h`, while a current texlive uses  `hebrew.ldf 2023/08/22 v2.4a`.  Lualatex is another engine which is unicode aware, you can choose it in the overleaf menu instead of pdflatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't see an option for choosing something other than pdflatex. I mean, I can't even find something with the name pdflatex

Comment: click on "menu" and then see https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVMKM.png

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you! I think it works now