# Hebrew text won't compile even though I use babel

Tags: errors, babel, languages, compilation-error, hebrew

so I'm using overleaf and for some reason Hebrew text won't compile, even when I use code that was perfectly fine a couple months ago. Here's some problematic code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
למה זה לא עובד?
\end{document}
```

Specifically, the error I get is "unicode character X not set up for use with LaTeX". Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: FWIW, I don't experience any issues with your code on my system, which uses MacTeX2023 with all updates applied. Given that the issue may be Overleaf-specific issue, I would like to suggest that you contact the Overleaf Helpdesk directly and ask for assistance. Their LaTeX support staff are top notch.

Comment: try removing `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` which is defined to do nothing in current releases, but could give errors in older ones

Comment: the support for hebrew with pdflatex on overleaf is imho not up-to-date. Try with lualatex instead, see the comments here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/706117/2388