# Typesetting in different languages

Tags: languages

I want to understand the way to enable and use latex to typeset in different languages.  Would one just type language glyphs in the latex document, and would one be using utf8 ?  Latex does provide the possibility of inserting diacritic marks (e.g. `H\^otel`), but it would be a strange thing to read when writing in french say.

I am using `lualatex`.  Have encountered `fontspec` and `babel`.  But what is one to use ?

Comment: Many questions already on this site: search for the `French` and `babel` tags to begin with: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/babel%2bfrench?tab=Newest

Comment: With `lualatex` your input should be utf-8.

Comment: So I can just input the language utf8 marks and lualatex will render appropriately ?

Comment: Yes, that’s right. Hôtel.

Comment: Yes you just type them any unicode glyph can be rendered provided  you have the font(s) that support it.

Comment: Without lualatex, your input should also be utf-8 if you are using LaTeX and any reasonably recent distribution.

Comment: You need also a localization package like `babel` to get translated strings like, eg, ‘Chapitre’ and proper hyphenation and line breaking. The `babel` style for French is very complete and customizable.

Comment: You just input `Hôtel`, where's the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I’m afraid the accepted answer isn’t quite <del>correct</del> complete (sorry, @Mico ). There are no line breaks with the CJK scripts and the Hebrew text is reversed (in addition, captions, hyphenation rules and the like aren’t activated). Actually, just setting the font isn’t enough and you need a multilingual package like `babel` . Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish, french]{babel}

\babelprovide{chinese}
\babelfont[chinese]{rm}{IPAexMincho}

\begin{document}

Plus ça change, plus c'est la même chose!

\foreignlanguage{spanish}{Español.}

\selectlanguage{chinese}

唯転冷応世黒式歌宿首己政転暮宿領体解。界済省物鯉権検米員燃惑稿。著変国上究初保前訴団婚雄就生術。実辞横掲中載自盗者洋同込迫。読力紙権促事惣者前回選根著都。

\end{document}
```

[image]

For Hebrew, see [Can anyone provide s minimal example of Hebrew/English document using Luatex/babel? (MacOS/TeXShop)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705243/can-anyone-provide-s-minimal-example-of-hebrew-english-document-using-luatex-bab/705244#705244).

Comment: The fact that I didn't mention the `babel` package in my answer should *not* be interpreted as me somehow signalling that `babel` is unimportant when it comes to proper typesetting. I simply interpreted the OP's query narrowly, as asking about how to enter various glyphs; cf. `H\^otel` vs. `Hôtel`. Well, the OP subsequent question, "Would you use `fontspec` rather than `babel`?", does reveal a degree of confusion on the OP's part that I truly hadn't anticipated.

Comment: @Mico `del`eted ‘correct’ and added ‘complete’.

Comment: @Mico Stricty speaking you re both correct, and I have also interpreted the OPs question incorrectly. I have a document where I typeset all current Unicode scripts with only minmal support from Babel. I used fallback fonts  The document mostly typesets unicode tables for each script and a few paragraphs of mostly English text, interspersed with some script(s) and IPA pronunciations.

Comment: @Mico  Now and then there is a paragraph for the "other" script as well. So IMHO fontspec for the glyphs of the script + Babel for the typographical conventions, captions, hyphenation rules, occassional maths aand other macros  etc. What we are still missing is  still proper indexing (I imagine Babel some day generating .ist like files).upmendex is a very promising in this respect.

Comment: @yannisl My attempts wrt indexing are closely related to one of my packages (namely, `esindex`). But I’ve never fully developed these ideas (they are in my todo list) and I wonder if it’s a task for babel or for a language aware indexing package. Anyway, as you pointed out, `upmendex` is very promising, and to a large extent a reality. Suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: It will be nice if it is integrated, as you already have all the .ini files, but to be honest I am also not very sure if it is a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Lua(La)TeX's one and only recognized *input* encoding scheme is utf8. (Aside: ASCII is a subset of utf8.) I suggest you load the [fontspec](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package and choose fonts that contain the glyphs you need for the language, or languages, you're writing in.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} % for \newfontfamily macro
\newfontfamily{\TC}{Noto Serif TC}
\newfontfamily{\JP}{Noto Serif TC}
\newfontfamily{\KA}{Noto Sans Kannada}

\begin{document} % "Hello World" in various languages...

\TC 
你好世界。

\JP 
こんにちは世界。

\KA 
ಹಲೋ ವರ್ಲ್ಡ್.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you use `fontspec` rather than `babel` ?

Comment: @Ragonese - [babel](https://ctan.org/pkg/babel) and [fontspec](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) do completely different things. They are *not* substitutes, as your question would appear to claim. Please read the first few pages of each package's user guide to familiarize yourself with what these packages do.

Comment: @Mico But the OP is about languages, not about fonts.

Comment: @JavierBezos - IMNSHO, the query is about three things: languages that employ glyphs not contained in the basic 26-letter Latin alphabet, ways to generate these glyphs, *and* fonts that make it easy to access language-specific glyphs. I focused my answer on the how-to-access-various-glyphs subtopic.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Oops, my bad. I meant to say "input encoding", not "font encoding". Let me fix this.

Comment: In the image provided, the Hebrew text renders backwards.

Comment: @AriBrodsky - Thanks. Clearly, I'd omitted some important considerations, making my answer quite incomplete (to use JavierBezos's term). To simplify things for now, I've omitted Hebrew.